# Android: Frize Splash screen page open second time

Tags: android

In my splash screen Activity i have get data from notification using (FCM). When first time open my app there is no problem it's fine but close my app and again open then only show splash screen

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
                        if (key.equals("WOID")&& value != null) {
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("WONum", value);
                            b.putString("from", FROM_PUSH);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, xyz.class);
                            intent.putExtra("b", b);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
```

and after i use only this line of code it's OK. please give me your valuable seggation thank you...

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
```

Comment: It's possible that your ```getExtras``` is not ```null``` but there is no ```WOID``` key, in this case your app will be stuck in ```Splash```. You should also check if that ```if``` statement in the ```for``` loop has been executed at least once, if not do the same thing as you are doing in the ```else``` statement.

Comment: if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) is null so why else condition not call.